# Js code to make a different div tag to show up only works one way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to make a calender and I got it to be where you click an arrow it changes the month name. But for some reason it can only go backwards but not forwards. Here is my Js code and Html:

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/9e3ddso1/

```
    .
```

So when you click on the left button it goes backward but if you click on the right button it doesn't do anything. It goes ahead one month but it doesn't let you go more then one month.

Comment: You have click event for left only none for right.

Comment: To abide by the rules here on StackOverflow, you should paste the code that is relevant to your question directly into your question.  StackOverflow does not allow questions who's only reference to required code is in an external link because these external links have a habit of disappearing or getting changed rendering the original question worthless in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right 1"></span>
```

In html file but in JS file you are listening on `right1` event. Try to change above to:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right right1"></span>
```

and all similar `span` elements

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is because you do not have any classes referencing 'right' i.e. `'right1'` ,`right2`, `right3` etc. You need to change the code for each div to this, and update the right class accordingly, i.e. the last part of the span class. See code below for how you should change the first one:

```
<a>
    <div class="month1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left left1"></span>
        January
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right right1">  
        </span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you are missing your "right" as part of your "right1" class.

Alternatively, you could use a smaller version for the same effect.
https://jsfiddle.net/9e3ddso1/8/

```
var months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May"];

$('.month').on('click', '.left', function() {
    var $month = $(this).closest('.month');
    var newMonth = ($month.data('month') > 0 ? $month.data('month') - 1 : months.length - 1);

    $month.data('month', newMonth);
    $month.find('.description').html(months[newMonth]);
});

$('.month').on('click', '.right', function() {
    var $month = $(this).closest('.month');
    var newMonth = ($month.data('month') + 1) % months.length;

    $month.data('month', newMonth);
    $month.find('.description').html(months[newMonth]);
});
```

Comment: this is a good answer, as the code being used is far too cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

Saw your code.  Its not going forward because your classname are not correct. You missed `right` word in classname in your HTML.

For example: 
rather than `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right right1`, you have used `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right 1`.

Answer (score -1):

You forget the right classes on links:

https://jsfiddle.net/9e3ddso1/1/

```
.
```

Comment: Answers with little explanation and no illustrative examples and only links are pretty much never great answers and can always be improved with a more detailed explanation.